# JavaScript execCommand selection

Tags: javascript, html-lists, selection, contenteditable, execcommand

I have an editor that changes font sizes, colors, styles, etc. But when the text is in an ordered/unordered lists the numbers & bullets do not change. This is because the selection does not include the li tag only the selected text. I would like to get the styling around the li instead of just the text in the list.

```
<div contenteditable="true" onmouseup="setfontSize ();">
 My List
 <ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
 </ol>
</div>

<script>
 function setfontSize () {
    document.execCommand ('fontSize', false, 7);
 }
</script>
```

I would to achieve this when the items are selected:

```
<ol>
      <font size="7"><li>Item 1</li></font>
      <font size="7"><li>Item 2</li></font> 
      <font size="7"><li>Item 3</li></font>
</ol>
```

Instead of this:

```
<ol>
     <li><font size="7">Item 1</font></li>
     <li><font size="7">Item 2</font></li> 
     <li><font size="7">Item 3</font></li>
</ol>
```

Is that possible? Thank you.